# Can errno be set on success?

Tags: vxworks, errno

I've notice on my vxWorks 6 platform that calls to `write` on a socket complete successfully and return the number of bytes requested to be written, but also transform errno from 0 to 19 (`ENODEV`).

I found this quite surprising.

Can errno be set after a successful operation?

Answer (score 7):

On `errno.h` Wikipedia says:

> A value (the error number) is stored in errno by certain library
> functions when they detect errors. At program startup, the value
> stored is zero. **Library functions store only values greater than zero.**
> Any library function can alter the value stored before return, whether
> or not they detect errors. Most functions indicate that they detected
> an error by returning a special value, typically NULL for functions
> that return pointers, and −1 for functions that return integers. A few
> functions require the caller to preset errno to zero and test it
> afterwards to see if an error was detected.

So apart from the bizarre value of `ENODEV` for a socket `write` it seems reasonable to think that some internal operation set `errno` and `write` recovered (or didn't care) but was not permitted to reset `errno` to 0 or to what it was prior.

The implication is that `errno` cannot be considered meaningful except *immediately* after a function whose return value indicates that `errno` is meaningful.

From this follows the idea that `errno` cannot be used afterwards to infer failure among a sequence of `errno`-influencing operations.

Such a use could only be possible if library functions were clearing `errno` mid-sequence, but because they do not clear `errno`, internal recovered error conditions are still reflected in `errno`.

If you need to know whether a function failed, you need to check it's result right away, and **only** if it is applicable.

You cannot use the global shared variable `errno` to tunnel exit status through a hierarchy of function calls without also independently returning success/failure status through some other means.